# itertools combinations in tandem with looping

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, random, python-itertools

I have the following Python code. Because random is being used, it generates a new answer every time:

```
import random

import numpy as np

N = 64 # Given

T = 5 # Given

FinalLengths = []

for i in range(T):

    c = range(1, N)
    x = random.sample(c, 2) # Choose 2 random numbers between 1 and N-1
    LrgstNode = max(x)
    SmlstNode = min(x)
    RopeLengths = [SmlstNode, LrgstNode - SmlstNode, N - LrgstNode] 
    S = max(RopeLengths)
    N = S
    FinalLengths.append(S)

avgS = np.mean(FinalLengths) # Find average

print("The mean of S is {}".format(avgS))
```

My research has led me to possibly using itertools combinations in order to produce all possible combinations within the range and get the avg to converge. If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: You want all combinations of size 2, or all combinations of any possible size?

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* like you're after something like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

N = 64 # Given
T = 5 # Given

FinalLengths = []

for i in range(T):
  c = list(range(1, N))
  for x in combinations(c, 2):
    S = max([min(x), max(x) - min(x), N - max(x)])
    N = S
    FinalLengths.append(S)

avgS = np.mean(FinalLengths) # Find average

print("The mean of S is {}".format(avgS))
```

To use `combinations(l, size)` we can pass in a list `l` and the size of each combination tuple, and int `size`. That's all there is to it!

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, the problem states that there is a string with length N and integer coordinates (1,…,N−1). You select 2 unique coordinates at random without replacement, cut the string at those 2 coordinates, and take the longest of the resulting 3 pieces as the new string. This is done T times (as long as it is possible to cut the string at unique integer coordinates) and call the length of the final resulting string S. I am trying to find the average of S when T and N are given. I am still trying to wrap my head around the iterations versus the combinations

Comment: Ah, that's different. Why find the average though? Is this just an academic interest? This sounds like a maximization or minimization problem, not one in which the average would be useful...

Comment: You do have a point! ... The problem statement is worded strangely. Maybe we are supposed to find the average of just that final resulting string after all combinations are evaluated? Doesn't make sense to find the average over the five iterations because the string is getting smaller and smaller ... If so, how would that change things

Comment: Well really I'd start by clarifying the problem to be solved. Is this for a class or some other "academic" (i.e. not real-world facing) problem, such as an application or algorithm challenge, or is this to help meet some business goal? Either way, I'd get the problem clear, then just write the algorithm to the problem...